# can Same Gitlab project register runner token be used to register multiple ec2/vms as runners for same project?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to understand does a single project token can register a single runner only ?
suppose I have 3 ec2 machines which I want to use as gitlab runner for a particular gitlab project. I want to register  all of them automatically to the project.
Do I need to create separate token for each ec2 ? or can I use the same registration token